# Using iTunes Search API unable to find existing resource using iTunes ID

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

The specific case:

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/movie/112-weddings/id889327105/

Movie ID is `889327105`. However, neither of the following is able to find the resource:

- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=889327105&entity=movie
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=889327105
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?isbn=889327105
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?amgVideoId=889327105
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?upc=889327105

I have been able to reproduce this with almost any ID I have tried:

- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=593941435
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=834624061
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=519376363
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=875243978
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=594248614

Comment: does my answer helps for your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the resource with this :

- https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=112+weddings

And was able to get the info for this ID ( 988581839 ) :

- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=988581839

Comment: I have closed the question. The reason I was not able to see the resource, because I have to include country as part of the query, e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=593941435&country=gb. Otherwise it will default to `US`.

Comment: Are you able to open all of the URLs? (without adding "country" parameter).

Comment: Yes. Yours urls give me a resultCount 0. Mine the resource ;)